# how to implement onclick function for buttons in array

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart, addition

I am trying to perform addition to grandTotal textbox by adding value on every button click. But, all that happens is only addition for new variables is performed as opposed to adding variable to earlier total.

Below is the code: -

```
<div id = "cakeHook" class="recipe1"><p id="hook1title">Chocolate Cake</p></div>
<div id=  "cookieHook" class="recipe2"><p id="hook2title">Cookie</p></div>
<div id=  "grandTotalHook" class="grandTotalBox"><p id="hook3title">Total for the day</p></div>
```

JS:

```
var chocolateCakeIngredients = [];
var ckIng1 = {iname:"Flour", rate:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;($1.00/Cup)"};
var ckIng2 = {iname:"Sugar", rate:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;($0.50/Cup)"};

var chocolateIngredientsArray = []; 

ckIng1.value = 1.75;
ckIng2.value = 1;

chocolateIngredientsArray.push(ckIng1);
chocolateIngredientsArray.push(ckIng2);

chocolateIngredientsArray[0].id = "button1";
chocolateIngredientsArray[1].id = "button2";

var btn1 = ckIng1;
var btn2 = ckIng2;

chocolateCakeIngredients.push(ckIng1);
chocolateCakeIngredients.push(ckIng2);

var cakeHookDiv = document.getElementById("cakeHook");

function render (ingredientList) 
{
    var container = document.createElement("div"); //Created div for displaying chocolate cake list

    cakeHookDiv.appendChild(container); //Appending the div to main hook on page, i.e. cakeHook

    //Adding ingredients list to the chocolate cake

    var containerElementUl = document.createElement ("ul");
    var containerElementLi = document.createElement ("li");
    var containerElementLiButton = document.createElement ("button");
    containerElementLiButton.innerHTML = ingredientList.iname + ingredientList.rate;
    containerElementLi.appendChild(containerElementLiButton);
    containerElementUl.appendChild(containerElementLi);
    container.appendChild(containerElementUl);
    cakeHookDiv.appendChild(container);
}

render (chocolateCakeIngredients[0]);
render (chocolateCakeIngredients[1]);
render (chocolateCakeIngredients[2]);
render (chocolateCakeIngredients[3]);
render (chocolateCakeIngredients[4]);
render (chocolateCakeIngredients[5]);

var grandTotalDiv = document.getElementById("grandTotalHook");
var container3 = document.createElement("div");
grandTotalDiv.appendChild(container3);
var containerElement3 = document.createElement("input");
containerElement3.type = "text";
containerElement3.className = "grandTotalBox";
containerElement3.id = "total";
containerElement3.value = 0;
container3.appendChild(containerElement3);

var grandTotal = document.getElementById("total").value;
var counter = 0;
var currentValue = 0;
var add = function(valueToAdd){
alert("adding: " + valueToAdd);
currentValue += valueToAdd;
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = currentValue;

function addition () 
{
    var grandTotal = btn1.value;
    grandTotal += btn2.value;
    grandTotal += btn3.value;
    grandTotal += btn4.value;
}

btn1.onclick = addition ();
```

Comment: Please only supply the minimal amount of code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Can you pls help out with the problem?

Comment: I will help if you reduce your question down to the basics. There is a lot of code there that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Have reduced the code.. pls check.

Comment: OK, I've reduced the excessive white space and bad indenting. Now, please create a working version of your code in jsfiddle.com and then paste the link to that in your question...

Comment: Is there any other way than jsfiddle, am unable to get it running in it.

Comment: If it won't run in jsfiddle then I suggest the code you have doesn't work.